# Find OpenMP with Cmake by using the command line

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation, openmp

I'm struggling with OpenMP and Xcode.

I would like to use OpenMP on my project. So far, I have set up everything on my CMakeList.

Just to be clear, I have to generate the Xcode project by using the following command line :

```
cmake -G Xcode .
```

With this command line, I have a .xcodeproj project which is created and I just have to build the project using Xcode.

Now I would like to integrate OpenMP and obviously If I do nothing, I have an error saying that OpenMP has not been found.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_omp_set_nested", referenced from:
```

So I integrate on my CMakeList the following lines :

```
find_package(OpenMP)

if(OPENMP_FOUND)
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
  set(HAVE_OPENMP 1)
  message(STATUS "HAVE_OPENMP status ${HAVE_OPENMP}")
else(OPENMP_FOUND)
  message (STATUS "Not found OpenMP")
endif()
```

But during the compilation, OpenMP is not found.

```
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp=libomp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [ ]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [/openmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-Qopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-openmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-xopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [+Oopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-qsmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-mp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-fopenmp=libomp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [ ]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [/openmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-Qopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-openmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-xopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [+Oopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-qsmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-mp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.6.0_1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS)
```

So I looked for informations on the internet. 
I have installed clang-omp and was careful about using this following command line :

```
CC=clang-omp CXX=clang-omp++ cmake Xcode .
```

It worked, OpenMp is found but well I'm not satisfied because I need to generate an Xcode Project. So I used this time the following command line :

```
CC=clang-omp CXX=clang-omp++ cmake -G Xcode .
```

Notice the **-G** parameter.
And this time, it does not work...I suspect It's because of Xcode but I don't know how to deal with it.

After spending many times on this issue, I would like to know if there is a solution to make it work ?

Thank you very much in advance